# Expanding a div to the end of a page?

Tags: html, css

Using HTML/CSS how would I set a

```
<div>
```

to equal the remainer of the page, if there are statically defined divs?

I have part of my website that's going to be 400px wide, regardless of anything, that floats left. I want this div to fill up the remaining space on the right. Here's an image of what I'm talking about if it doesn't make sense.

http://gyazo.com/dd21a5566db57aa3fd1a7ea3a4f94207

I've tried things like

width:auto, 
and width:100% just takes up the full body of the page.

---

Code as requested:

```
echo '<div id="dashboard" class="clearfix">';
echo '<div class="dbspacer"><font style="padding-left: 2%">Account information</font></div>';
echo '<div class="dbinfobuffer">';
echo '<div class="dbwrap">';
echo '<div id="dbinfocontainer" style="padding-left: 2%">';
echo '<div class="numstatscontainer">';
echo '<ul class="numstatsblock">';
echo '<li>Account Balance:</br><font style="font-size: 32px; font-style:oblique;" color="#00CC00">$' . number_format($current_balance, 2) . '</font></br>-</li>';
echo '<li>Pending Balance:</br><font style="font-size: 32px; font-style:oblique;" color="#00CC00">$' . number_format($pending_balance, 2) . '</font></br>-</li>';
echo '</br>';
echo '<li>Monthly Sales:</br> ' . compareMonths(false, false, $this_month_sales, $last_month_sales). '</br>' . compareMonths(true, false, $this_month_sales, $last_month_sales) . '</li>';
echo '<li>Monthly Revenue:</br> ' . compareMonths(false, true, $this_month_revenue, $last_month_sales) . '</br>' . compareMonths(true, false, $this_month_revenue, $last_month_revenue) . '</li>';
echo '</br>';
echo '<li>Accumulative Sales:</br><font style="font-size: 32px; font-style:oblique;" color="#00CC00">$' . number_format($total_sales, 2) . '</font></br>-</li>';
echo '<li>Accumulative Revenue:</br><font style="font-size: 32px; font-style:oblique;" color="#00CC00">$' . number_format($total_revenue, 2) . '</font></br>-</li>';
echo '</div>'; // div - numstatscontainer
echo '<div class="graphcontainer">';
include_once 'get_chart.php';
echo '</div>'; // div - graphcontainer
echo '</div>'; // div - dbinfocontainer 
echo '</div>'; // div - dbwrap
echo '</div>'; // div - dbinfo buffer
echo '</div>'; // div - dashboard
```

?>

Css:

.dbwrap {

```
display: table; 
    width: 100%;
}
.dbinfobuffer {
    width: 100%;
    border-top-color:#999;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    padding-top: 1%;
    display: table-cell;
}
.graphcontainer {
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px;
    border-style:dashed;
    border-color:#999;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS?

Comment: not exactly sure how that's relevent to the question of expanding a div, but sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `display: table-cell` property. Here's an example that I've quickly coded for you:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#one {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 400px;
  background: blue;
  height: 300px;
}
#two {
  display: table-cell;
  background: pink;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

There are two div's, `#one` and `#two`. `#one` has a fixed width of `400px` whilst `#two` takes up the leftover space. Both of these div's have been assigned the `display: table-cell` property and they're wrapped with another `div` which has been assigned the `display: table` property.

Comment: Ah, I see-- I never thought about it like that, I was always trying to do some really strange math.

Comment: @Christian.tucker THis is the best way to achieve the sort of a layout which you're trying to create.

Comment: How did you embed a snippet to your answer?

Comment: @Christian.tucker Please read this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: This method for some reason isn't working, see image - http://gyazo.com/746b4b920c96bb6c283186795c53ef94 - I'll update the code in the main thread.

Comment: @christian.tucker Are you adding `display: table;` to the parent container?

Comment: @christian.tucker remove `width: 100%;` under the CSS for `.dbinfobuffer`and then try.

Comment: Produces the following - gyazo.com/05512ed69519b7b1815ed12f110c640e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64275/discussion-between-fahad-hasan-and-christian-tucker).